# Keeping the body background image fixed on the iphone

Tags: iphone, css, scroll, background-image, fixed

I have been trying for days to get the background image on my JQM iPhone app to remain fixed and to have the content scroll above it.

Having research many of the answers given I have the following piece of code:

```
body {
 background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
 background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Using this achieves the desired effect when previewing the app in Safari on my desktop however when I view the app on my iPhone(4s - 6.1.3) the background scrolls with the content.

I have tried many different methods to achieve what I require but so far I have not been successful. As the majority of apps use this method I am sure it is something very simple which I am missing.

Any advice would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: Put an UIImageView before your Scrollview or tableView and make your scrollview's or tableview's background as a clear color or i can say transparent color. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below one
body {
 background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-size:100%;
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately using that code still has not solved the problem.